# Real-time timeline function like tweetdeck?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm creating an app using python/tweepy

I'm able to use the StreamListener to get real time "timeline" when indicating a "topic" or #, $, etc.

Is there a way to have a real-time timeline function similar to tweetdeck or an embedded widget for a website for the user ID? non-stop

When using api.user_timeline receiving the 20 most recent tweepy.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is a Python library, so there's really no way to use it directly on a website. You could send the data from the stream to a browser using WebSockets or AJAX long polling, however.

There's no way to have the Userstream endpoint send tweets to you any faster - all of that happens on Twitter's end. I'm not sure why Tweetdeck would receive them faster, but there's nothing than can be done except to contact Twitter, if you're getting a slow speed.